# How to make a chart without the y-axis on flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, charts

How to make a chart without the y-axis on flutter.

I want to make One-dimensional chart. like the picture

Is there anyone who can help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh7RK.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a `LinearGraph` widget as depicted in the image provided in the question. You just need to add the widget to your main screen and also you can customize any part of it.

Below is the image of that widget, first is the one you have shown in the image and rest two are having `divider`s changed and also title.

[image]

Now the code for the main function where you will use that widget:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late List<Widget> labels;
  late List<String> fields;
  late double factor;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    factor = 0.7; //
    factor = 4 / 5;

    prepareFields();
    makeLabels();
  }

  void prepareFields() {
    fields = ['Under', 'Standard', 'Excess'];
  }

  void makeLabels() {
    labels = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
      labels.add(Text(fields[i]));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "HOME",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
          title: Text('Flutter'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                //you can also add your own divider widget and title
                //title field and divider fields are optional
                LinearGraph(
                  labels: labels,
                  factor: factor,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 40,),
                LinearGraph(labels: labels, factor: 0.45, divider: Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),),
                SizedBox(height: 40,),
                LinearGraph(labels: labels, factor: 0.25, divider: Icon(
                  Icons.account_circle_sharp,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),title: 'A new graph',),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the `linear_graph` widget code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LinearGraph extends StatefulWidget {
  List<Widget> labels;
  Widget? divider;
  String? title;

  ///keep factor in the range of [0,1]
  double factor;
  LinearGraph({Key? key, required this.labels, required this.factor, this.divider, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LinearGraph> createState() => _LinearGraphState();
}

class _LinearGraphState extends State<LinearGraph> {

  late List<Widget> dividers;
  late List<Widget> labels;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if(widget.factor > 1){
      widget.factor = 1;
    }else if(widget.factor < 0){
      widget.factor = 0;
    }

    makeDividers();
    makeLabels();
  }

  void makeDividers(){
    dividers = [];
    for(int i=0;i<widget.labels.length+1;i++){
      dividers.add(widget.divider??Container(
                height: 40,
                width: 4,
                color: Colors.black,
              ));
    }
  }

  void makeLabels(){
    labels = [];
    for(int i=0;i<widget.labels.length;i++){
      labels.add(Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: widget.labels[i],
        )
      ));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Text(widget.title??'Linear Graph', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Colors.black),),
        ),
        LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints){
            return Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(height: 4, color: Colors.black,),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: dividers,),
              Positioned(
                left: constraints.maxWidth*widget.factor -20/2,
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Icon(
                  Icons.circle,
                  size: 20,
                  color: Colors.red,
              ),
                ),)
            ],
          );
          },
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: labels,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```